# How to dynamically set bootstrap-datepicker's date value?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap datepicker along with a line highchart.

I want the datepicker date to update when the chart is zoomed. Once that event triggers I update the values of the datepicker. The values update fine but when the calendar is clicked, the date on the popup calendar is still the old date.

Here is my datepicker:

```
<div class="input-append date pull-right" id="dpStartDate" data-date="@DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <input class="span2" id="startDateText" size="16" type="text" value="@DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" readonly="">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

I have tried just updating the values using this code:

```
$('#dpStartDate').attr('data-date', startDate);
$('#startDateText').attr('value', startDate);
```

which updates the dates fine but doesn't set the calendar.

I've also tried triggering the onChange event, which also updates the dates but not the calendar:

```
$('#dpStartDate').trigger('changeDate', startDate);

$('#dpStartDate').datepicker()
    .on('show', function (ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
    })
    .on('changeDate', function (ev, date) {
        var startDate = new Date();
        if (date != undefined) {
            startDate = date;
            $('#dpStartDate').attr('data-date', startDate);
            $('#startDateText').attr('value', startDate);
        }
        else {
            startDate = ev.date;
            $('#dpStartDate').attr(startDate.getDate() + '/' + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + startDate.getFullYear());
            $('#startDateText').attr(startDate.getDate() + '/' + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + startDate.getFullYear());
        }
        $('#dpStartDate').datepicker('hide');
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Does anyone know if it's even possible to update the calendar like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 80):

This works for me

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("update", new Date());
```

Comment: This works, but it breaks format if you declared it on `html` . Like, if format is `"dd.mm.yyyy"` , when updating like this results `datetime` of format `"mm/dd/yyyy"` . Is there workaround for it ?

Comment: @Javidan I haven't tested, but maybe you could pass in a moment js date, and then specify the format.

Comment: Note that `datepicker` !=`datetimepicker`.

Comment: @Javidan the format will not break if you are using data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy", like <input type='text' name="myDateCtrl" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="Select date" />

Answer (score 43):

```
var startDate = new Date();

$('#dpStartDate').data({date: startDate}).datepicker('update').children("input").val(startDate);
```

another way

```
$('#dpStartDate').data({date: '2012-08-08'});
$('#dpStartDate').datepicker('update');
$('#dpStartDate').datepicker().children('input').val('2012-08-08');
```

1. set the calendar date on property data-date
2. update (required)
3. set the input value (remember the input is child of datepicker).

this way you are setting the date to '2012-08-08'

Comment: Can you add a little bit of explanation to your code snippet? :)

Comment: why doesn't the datepicker listen for changes in the text input and do this itself?

Comment: ...and that code does not work, this code works $('#dpStartDate').datepicker('update', '2012-08-08');

Comment: How can Set format of date after update call?
e.g. Val I set is `"2012-08-12 06:05:04"` and I want to set format after update is `"12/08/2012 06:05:04"`?

Is it possible how ?

My Code:
`$('#start').datepicker("setValue", "2014-08-08 6:05:04" );`
`$("$start").datepicker("update");`
`$("#start").datetimepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii', language: 'fr', autoclose: true, todayBtn: true});`

Comment: After set date value when I click on datepicker input it will show me date and month proper but year started from "1989". I don't know why?

Comment: Just add one `$('#dpStartDate').datepicker().children('input').trigger('blur');` at the end, and the field will be formated.

Comment: It works but it doesnt set "active" class to the .day

Answer (score 33):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date);
```

Comment: isn't it only for Jquery? Does it work with Bootstrap datepicker too?

Comment: yes, Bootstrap datepicker have similar method

Answer (score 15):

Try this code,

```
$(".endDate").datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true
}).datepicker("update", "10/10/2016");
```

this will update date and apply format `dd/mm/yyyy` as well.

Answer (score 13):

Better to use :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date);
```

instead of

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("update", new Date);
```

If you use update, event changeDate isn't triggered.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me,

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker("setValue", '01/10/2014' );
$('#datepicker').datepicker("setValue", new Date(2008,9,03));
```

Comment: Yes this was it form me! I'm not sure why the date format wouldn't work, but the formatted date works by setting the UI value and preselecting the date on the calendar popup. The date object isn't working to set the calendar popup for myself.

Answer (score 4):

When using the methods of other answers, the configured options are lost, to correct it, you can use a global configuration:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.startDate = "0";
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = "es";
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.autoclose = true;
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayHighlight = true;
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayBtn = true;
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.weekStart = 1;
```

Now you can use the update method without losing the options:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("update", new Date("30/11/2018"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Code:

```
var startDate = "2019-03-12"; //Date Format YYYY-MM-DD

$('#datepicker').val(startDate).datepicker("update");
```

Explanation:

Datepicker(input field) Selector #datepicker.

Update input field.

Call datepicker with option update.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do 'setValue' and 'update' in order to get it to work completely

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setValue', '2014-01-29').datepicker('update');
```

Comment: I have tried it from console. it is not working.
$('#start').datepicker('setValue', '2014-01-29').datepicker('update');

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using @AshwinParmar? I'm using Bootstrap v4.

Answer (score 3):

That really works.

Simple,

Easy to understand,

Single method to set and update plugin which worked for me.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("update", new Date());
```

Other ways to update

```
$('.datepicker').data({date: '2015-01-01'});
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update');
```

Dont forget to call `update` manually.

Comment: This is **EXACLY** the same as [@Imran's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19953892/662581) you didn't add anything to an answer that already existed for almost 5 month **before** your answer.

Comment: No problem, don't need to apologise for that. When this occur you can always up-vote the answer that already exists. But your answer is right, it's just a "copy" from +Imran's and I just wanted to point that out

Comment: Shouldn't this answer be deleted as a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

For datetimepickers use this this work for me

```
$('#lastdate1').data({date: '2016-07-05'});
$('#lastdate1').datetimepicker('update');
$('#lastdate1').datetimepicker().children('input').val('2016-07-05');
```

Comment: The only answer from here which worked for me (v1.6.4). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For **Bootstrap 4**

If you are using input group in Bootstrap, you need to attach the new date to parent of the textbox, otherwise if you click on the calendar icon and click outside the date will be cleared.

```
<div class="input-group date" id="my-date-component">
   <input type="text" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to set date to `input-group.date`.

```
$('#my-date-component').datepicker("update", new Date("01/10/2014"));
```

Also check datepicker [update](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update) method

Answer (score 2):

Please note that if you initiate a datepicker with a custom format, you can pass the simple string date as the second argument. This saves a few lines.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
});

$('.selector').datepicker('update', '13/09/2019');
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('#DateDepenseInput').val("2020-12-28")` 
the Format should be like Year-Month-Day 
It worked well for me ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Bootstrap DatePicker version 4+](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

> Note All functions are accessed via the data attribute e.g.
>   $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()

To set the date value, your codes should be like

```
$("#datetimepicker").data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way like this (one line)

```
$('#startDateText').val(startDate).datepicker("update");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$('#dpStartDate').data("date", startDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also this way:

```
  $("#startDateText").datepicker({
                toValue: function (date, format, language) {
                    var d = new Date(date);
                    d.setDate(d.getDate());
                    return new Date(d);
                },
                autoclose: true
            });
```

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format

Answer (score 0):

@Imran answer works for textboxes

for applying the datepicker to a div use this:

```
$('#div_id').attr("data-date", '1 January 2017');
$('#div_id').datepicker("update");
```

comma-delim multiple dates:

```
$('#div_id').attr("data-date", '1 January 2017,2 January 2017,3 January 2017');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method like :

```
qsFromDate = '2017-05-10';
$("#dtMinDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date(qsFromDate));
$('#dtMinDate').datepicker('update');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date('01/11/2016 10:23 AM')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker
You need to set the date value by:
$('#datetimepicker1').data('datetimepicker').setDate(new Date(value));

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate','25-05-2020').datepicker('fill');
```

This works for me when `setDate` is not updating the date picker text field value on browser. " The additional `.datepicker('fill');`" repopulate the bootstrap `datepicker` for new date which is set by `setDate` method.

Answer (score 0):

On page load if you dont want to fire the changeDate event which I didnt

```
$('#calendarDatePicker').data("date", new Date());
$('#calendarDatePicker').datapicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me. Simply put the following one.

```
$('.className').datepicker('setDate', 'now');
```