# Is it possible to use setDate on an inline Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Does anyone know how to setDate on an inline calendar in Bootstrap Datepicker from eternicode(https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).  I've been struggling to figure this out, but alas have fallen short.  I can get it to work with an input, but not for the inline view.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507508/bootstrap-datepicker-set-date-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution seems to be:

```js
the_date = new Date(2013, 10, 25);
$('#datepicker').datepicker('update', the_date);
```