# Bootstrap Datetimepicker set Time programmatically from Epoch

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I have a simple Datetimepicker:

```
$('#deadline_picker').datetimepicker();
```

Trivially I can produce the utc / or local date string with `var x= new Date(timestamp)` or `var x= (new Date(timestamp)).toUTCString()`. And Assign it as a value to the field - `$('#deadline_picker').val(x)`

But for one the Datetime Picker object does not seem responsive to programmatic changes (if the Calendar has a certain date selected it will still show the same date selected and it does not appear to be timezone conscious). It is very critical for me to be able to set an exact equivalent of the Epoch time programmatically. Supposedly the datetimepicker has API methods, but the docs don't have a single example.

Edit: I'm using the copy that's referenced as being currently maintained: 
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Edit2: Apparently it has different methods from: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ 
But neither of them seem to have Timezone support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that one of the commonly used ones at https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker will not take (new Date).toUTCString() as an argument and is not helpful. 
The one I mentioned in my question: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker  - Also does not appear to take (new Date()) strings of either kind, but it will take both moment() and moment.utc() objects, so in my case this worked. (Deadline is in a table row represented visually as a Timestring without seconds, year or milliseconds, to preserve datatable space).

```
$td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
var timestamp = moment.utc($td.eq(2).attr('value')*1000);
$('#deadline_picker').data("DateTimePicker").setDate(deadline);
```

This can be reversed with:

```
$('#deadline_picker').data("DateTimePicker").getDate().unix()
```

Comment: `setDate` didn't exist with the version I was using, had to use the `date` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
    var x= (new Date(timestamp)).toUTCString();
    $('#deadline_picker').datetimepicker("update", x);
```

If this didnt work, try this:

```
    $('#deadline_picker').data({date: x});
    $('#deadline_picker').datetimepicker('update');
    $('#deadline_picker').datetimepicker().children('input').val(x);
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507508/bootstrap-datepicker-set-date-using-jquery)

Comment: That's what I was trying - maybe I'm using the wrong one? There seem to be like 3 forks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more possibilities. You'll notice I've reference a link for a similar question. On that thread there's a few more options. I believe that the datetimepicker you're using is based of that one.

Comment: It seems it has other methods. I finally found the docs: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ the problem appears to be that both this and the other one you mentioned don't preserve TZ info. So for example the rest of your contents can show UTC or Local Time but the DatetimePicker has to be coarsed later -