# bootstrap datepicker set date to curent date

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I would like to automatically set the date of today but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="input-append date">
     <input type="text" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="date_debut" readonly>
     <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>


$('#date_debut').datepicker({
    setDate: new Date(),
    autoclose: true
});
```

The date is set when i click but I want it set whithout clicking in the date input

Edit => Maybe there is a problem with my requires ? The usuals way with are working in peoples projects doesn't in mine ....

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/js/collapse_bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/css.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: just add `value` attribute with current date to `date_debut` input?

Comment: yes it works for a static date but how to do it with the date of ' today ' ?

Comment: I meant when you output your `html` portion of date input, give it a default value of today did you get me?

Comment: Oh i understand but i dont print it with some JS, it is in a html page. I just set the values with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#date_debut').datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    autoclose: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something like this:

```
$("#date_debut").datepicker("update", new Date());
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953892/3172092

**Update:** before initializing your `datepicker` instance you can first set the value to the input, example:

```
$("#date_debut").val('2014-10-13');

// next
$('#date_debut').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: No, i don't understand why all that solutions doesn't work in my project ... Maybe i will use George Garchagudashvili technic and generate the html code for my datepicker setting a value field with the curent date in jquery. Is it a good way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works that way but it's not very ... clean

My html code =>

```
<div class="input-append date" id="print_date_debut">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

My javascript code in an other file =>

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0!`

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd}
if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
console.log(today);

$j("#print_date_debut").prepend("<input type=\"text\" value=\""+today+"\" data-date-format=\"yyyy-mm-dd\" id=\"date_debut\" readonly>");

$j('#date_debut').datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    autoclose: true
});
```