# How to preselect date in bootstrap 3 datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using  [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for that I am trying following

```
<div class='input-group date datetimepicker1'>
     <input type='text' name="actEndDate" placeholder="End Date"  class="form-control" required/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

and calling it by following

```
 $(".datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
```

Its working fine

now i am changing date using JavaScript on clicking of other field i have date formate like  11/4/2015 and for that i am trying following

```
   $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: "11/1/2013"

    });
```

now how to preselect date ?

> Note : its different from jquery datepicker

Comment: Have you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507508/bootstrap-datepicker-set-date-using-jquery

Comment: @PaolaG as you can see datepicker is different form datetimepicker :(

Answer (score 0):

I see this way for your question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                    disabledDates: [
                        moment("10/2/2013"),
                        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

you can see [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) page for other doubt.

Setting **defaultDate** parameter is the right method to resolve it.