# How to update multiple inputs with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm working on a form that has fields for `start date` and `end date`, using bootstrap-datepicker.

For convenience, any time the user updates `start date`, I want `end date` to update to match `start date`. (Changing end date should not change start date though).

I'm pretty new to jQuery, but this is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dateinput').datepicker();
  $('#id_start_date').change(function() {
    var startDate = $(this).val();
    $('#id_end_date').val(startDate);
  });
});

<input class="dateinput" id="id_start_date" name="start_date" type="text" />
<input class="dateinput" id="id_end_date" name="end_date" type="text" />
```

This almost works; using the datepicker on `start date` correctly updates `end date`. But then if I try to click on the `end date` field, its datepicker still has a stale value for `end date` (calendar reflects the old value for `end date`).

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400149/5802442) suggests I need to call the datepicker's `update()` function when I update the input's `val()`. But at the time of changing `start date`, `end date`'s datepicker isn't in the DOM (so I don't think I can target it with `$('.dateinput')`).

I've also tried targeting it with `$('#id_end_date').datepicker('update');` but this doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `setDate` method to set the value for `bootstrap datepicker`

```
$('#id_end_date').datepicker('setDate',startDate)
```