# Issue with bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datepicker

A site that I'm maintaining at the moment uses bootstrap (v3.1.1) and Ace Admin theme (http://ace.jeka.by/), which doesn't appear to be actively maintained anymore.

I'm also using Knockout and having difficulty getting a datepicker on the form to respect the format that I want it to use. There are a number of questions here in relation to getting Knockout to play nicely with the BS datepicker.

The datepicker in question is eyecon's one, not eternicode's. As the former is deeply embedded in the Ace Admin theme it doesn't look trival to swap it out. The HTML5 date input isn't widely enough supported for me to use it.

Fortunately I'm almost there with it, except for the fact the datepicker isn't honouring the format I'm telling it to use.

I use a KO binding as follows:

**JS:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            // Register change callbacks to update the model if the control changes.
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element,
                "change",
                function() {
                    var value = valueAccessor();
                    value(moment(element.value).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
                });
        },
        // Update the control whenever the view model changes
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            element.value = moment(value()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        }
    };
```

**HTML:**

```
 <input class="datepicker form-control" data-bind="datepicker: BirthDetails().DateOfBirth, value: BirthDetails().DateOfBirth, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" />
```

**Result:**
[image: Result]

Comment: I'm not sure it'll be much use here, but are you aware of [knockstrap](https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/)? It's designed to bridge the gap between knockout and bootstrap - quite helpful in some situations.

Comment: Try `ko.unwrapObservable` before accessing the `valueAccessor`... And yes, knockstrap is a library worth looking at...

Comment: @gkb Your suggestion to use    unwrapObservable  causes KO to go a line that reads:    ex.message = "Unable to process binding \"" + bindingKey + ": " + bindings[bindingKey] + "\"\nMessage: " + ex.message;

Comment: @noonand - do you have a fiddle to look at?

Comment: @JamesThorpe had a look at knockstrap and while it looks very useful I can't see how it can help in this instance?

Comment: That's why I said "I'm not sure it'll be much use here" - but in the future it could be if you're using both together.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/noonand/k0jocvLa/

Comment: @JamesThorpe definitely one to store, many thanks for pointing it out. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be in the HTML, in the `data-bind` directive I had `text` and `datepicker` attributes. On debugging, it appeared one was competing with the other so I removed the `text` one and all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the demo for the [Bootstrap's date-picker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php), I think you should specify the format that you want as an option and then build the datepicker like below -

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {    
  $(element).datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
  });
}
```

You can find the possible options [here](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Also, inside of the update handler, use `ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())` to get the current value you need to set the datepicker to like so -

```
var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); 
// format it (using moment like you are currently doing)
// set the datepicker to the formatted value
$(element).datepicker("update", value);
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507508/how-to-dynamically-set-bootstrap-datepickers-date-value) on how to update it. (although, I couldn't find any such method in the documentation)