# add more datetime value using textbox value in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie in ASP.net MVC..so i have a difficult here:

[image]

I have 3 element : Purchase Date, Warranty Period and Expired Date. Purchase Date is a EditorFor with datePicker class so user can pick a date. Warranty Date is a EditorFor where user put a int number such as 1 , 3, 6, 12 (Months). And Expired Period is a EditorFor with "readonly" class so user can't modified this.
And my question is when user choosed a date in Purchase Date and input value in Warranty Date. How to auto add a value into Expired Date with formula: Expired Date = Purchase Date + Warranty Period...Please help me... thank you all..

Comment: You need javascript to respond to client side events (and your `ExpiredDate` should not be a form control - just text)

Comment: can you be more detail sir...thank a lot

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Do some research and then show what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically set bootstrap-datepicker's date value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507508/how-to-dynamically-set-bootstrap-datepickers-date-value)

Answer (score 0):

try wiring up `change` events with *Purchase Date* and *Warranty Period* like:

```
var pd=document.getElementById("<Id of Purchase Date>");
pd.onchange=function(){
    calculateExpiry();
};
var wp=document.getElementById("<Id of Warranty>");
wp.onchange=function(){
    calculateExpiry();
};

var we=document.getElementById("<Id of Warranty Expiry>");
function calculateExpiry(){
    var d=pd.value;
    if(d===""){
    return;
    }
    var w=wp.value;
    if(w===""){
    return;
    }
    var a=d.split("-");//suppose your date is displayed as yyyy-mm-dd (2017-07-21)
    var m=+a[1];
    m+= +w;
    var y=0;
    if(m>12){
        y+=1;
        m-=12;
    }

    we.value=+a[0]+y + "-" + a[1]-1 +"-" + +a[2]);
}
```

This is very crude and quite verbose. You can try jQuery etc to do event handling. Also remember no error checking/handling is done here.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to execute code on the web browser of the user. You cannot to that with `ASP.NET` since all the code is executed when generating the page. Once the page is sent to the user, `ASP.NET` cannot do anything to change the page.

To execute code on the user's web browser you need to use `Javascript`.

To include `Javascript` in a web page, simply use the `<script>` tag and put code in it.

```
<script>
// Put the javascript code here
</script>
```

Usually the script tag goes right before the closing `</body>` tag. So it would do something like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- Content of the page here -->

    <script>
        // Put the javascript code here
    </script>

</body>
```

**EDIT:** I just saw @TheVillageIdiot wrote the code to do what you want. I highly suggest you still learn a bit of `Javascript` because it is used a lot in web development.