# Update bootstrap datepicker value in year only mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to set year of datepicker in edit case

I have created datepicker with year only mode using following code.

```
$(".datepickeryearonly").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years",
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```

Now I want to update its value.

I have tried

```
$('input[name="abcd"]').parents('.datepickeryearonly').first().datepicker('setDate','YYYY');
```

and

```
$('input[name="abcd"]').val('YYYY')
```

which is NOT WORKING.

HTML :

```
<div class="datepickeryearonly">
    <input class="form-control" name="abcd" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507508/how-to-dynamically-set-bootstrap-datepickers-date-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Update for update the date. Please try

```js
$(".datepickeryearonly").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years",
    minViewMode: "years"
});

$('input[name="abcd"]').parents('.datepickeryearonly').first().datepicker('update','2001');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

<div class="datepickeryearonly">
    <input class="form-control" name="abcd" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a date object to set the date.

```
$('input[name="abcd"]').parents('.datepickeryearonly').first().datepicker('setDate',new Date());
```

I made a fiddle setting the date to whatever year you fill in the second box, please check it out!

https://jsfiddle.net/74mnxhkv/3/